Did Jim Carrey get away with lying in 'Liar Liar'?
In the movie 'Liar Liar', on a particular day Jim Carrey cannot tell a lie. But I believe that he did make a false statement that day.
In the 'The pen is blue' scene he threatened his hand (@1:50 here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAE7uOO_4v4), "Write it or I'll break it off." A few seconds later, he writes 'blue' with a blue pen, then makes no subsequent attempt to maim himself.
From the context, we can infer that his statement means, "If my hand does not write 'red' with a blue pen, then I will break my hand off." So, since Carrey did not break off his hand, his statement is false. Symbolically:

If A then B.
A.
Thus B.
However, ~B.
Therefore, B ^ ~B.
Hence, not (if A then B).

Did Carrey really manage to lie? Or is there a subtle bit of context that would allow for Carrey's statement to actually be true?

"It" is ambiguous here and from context I believe it means "the color of the pen" instead of "red" since it's meant to be a lie. Since the demand is to write the color of the pen he told the truth and is no longer obligated to maim himself.

I don't think imperative ("write it") has truth value, so his phrase wasn't even a statement, in particular not a lie.

These are good points, you have convinced me that Carrey did not lie. Thank you both!

@mihaild "Write it" doesn't have a truth value, but "I'll break it off" does.

I think when he said it he intended to follow through, but changed his mind after the hand's impressive display of self-defense right after.

@AkivaWeinberger sure, but not having truth value is explosive: if $A$ doesn't have truth value, $A \vee B$ also doesn't.

Since imperatives like "write it" and "write a poem" don't have truth values (regardless of whether they are obeyed, and of the ambiguity of "it"), they are not propositional-logic sentences. As such, Carrey did not actually make any false declaration.
On the other hand, the assertion "I shall write a poem" is a lie if uttered with no intention to perform the task.
